# ESB Build issue from source code

Tags: maven, wso2, esb

I have downloaded platform source code and trying to build ESB 4.6.0 "by running mvn clean install inside "carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/patch-releases/4.0.6/"

I am getting following error message -

Installation failed.
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be foun
d.
 Software being installed: WSO2 Carbon - Axis2 Transport HTTP Pass-through Featu
re 1.0.2 (org.wso2.carbon.transports.passthru.feature.group 1.0.2)
 Missing requirement: WSO2 Carbon - Axis2 Transport HTTP Pass-through Feature 1.
0.2 (org.wso2.carbon.transports.passthru.feature.group 1.0.2) requires 'org.wso2
.carbon.core.server.feature.group [4.1.0,4.2.0)' but it could not be found
Application failed, log file location: C:\Users\user.m2\repository\org\eclipse\
tycho\tycho-p2-runtime\0.13.0\eclipse\configuration\1368415821993.log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you comment out following two code segments in pom.xml[1] and continue build using "mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Dproduct=esb" inside "carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/patch-releases/4.0.6/" . this passthru feature is already included in synapse code. so you can remove it.

```
@line 178
<featureArtifactDef>org.wso2.carbon:org.wso2.carbon.transports.passthru.feature:${passthru.transport.patch.version}</featureArtifactDef>

@line 512
    <feature>
          <id>org.wso2.carbon.transports.passthru.feature.group</id>
          <version>${passthru.transport.patch.version}</version>
    </feature>
```

[1] https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/products/esb/4.6.0/modules/p2-profile/pom.xml

Comment: Thanks, that worked I can see ESB distribution is created. Where can I find source code of ESB so that I can import in eclipse and perform some changes and re-build the distribution.

Comment: This is a very tricky part. You have to know basics of a WSO2 product in ordered to achieve your task. This is a very brief introduction in top down manner. will give it in several comments. **PART 1** A WSO2 product has its own set of features which are integrated into [WSO2 carbon core](http://wso2.com/products/carbon/). This integration happens at p2-profile maven module. All Features (including all other Products' features) are located in feature directory (eg: http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/features/).

Comment: A feature is self contain bundle. It can have one or many components. At the build time, components' jars & resources/configuration files, which are related to that specific feature packed into a single feature (zip). A component is where actual source code is located. All components located in component directory. (eg: http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/tags/4.0.7/components/). Service-stubs are the components that do wsdl2java code generations. Dependencies are external code bases that used in Products. ( for ESB, synapse) .

Comment: Now let's get back to your requirement. Note that If you need to do synapse level code changes, you have to do it in dependencies/synapse.)  First you have to build eclipse projects using maven ( mvn eclipse:eclipse ) and import them into eclipse. Do your changes.  If you did synapse level changes, build it first. Then build only changed components. then build affected features. Then build whole ESB product in product/ESB/ .  Thanks.